# Custom URL rewrite not working in pwa magento 2 site

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, pwa

Custom URL rewrite not working in pwa magento 2 site

The below setting is enabled
General -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites -> Yes
any other setting or configuration is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution we have to whitelist the custom url from below mentioned configuration setting

Additional for PWA after URL rewrite from Marketting. we have to whitelist the URL from
Store > Configuration > General > Web > UPWARD PWA Configuration

you can add like below - line break wise
register
contact